# realm.object is nil on iOS 11 but it's not on iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, realm

```
var feed: Results<Feed> {
    get {
        return realm.objects(Feed.self)
    }
}
```

I have XCode 9, Swift 3.2, and Realm 2.10.2

On iOS 10, feed is set to something like `Results<Feed> <0x7f8a2bb3c2b0> ()` but on iOS 11 it crashes on the return statement and gives me `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Does anyone have an idea why this is? It seems like I'm running into this error after I updated realm from 2.10.1 ~> 2.10.2

Comment: I think you'll need to share more information. There's no use of optionals in the code snippet you've provided, AFAICT (unless you're using an implicitly-unwrapped optional for your `realm` property?)

Comment: The app crashes on `return realm.objects(Feed.self)` with that fatal error message.

Comment: Where is `realm` declared, and what does that declaration look like?

Comment: it is declared inside `init`. I could move it to inside `get{}` as well but that still giving me a nil

Comment: Please share the code where the `realm` property is declared, and where it is initialized. From what you're shared it is the only possible place where an optional could be being unwrapped.

Comment: The issue was with the migration. I had to increment `schemaVersion`. I'm not really sure why though because I haven't changed the model. I guess this is required on library updates?

Comment: My guess is that the issue has to do with multithreading, which can cause all sorts of issues with realm.

Comment: I think there may have been changes between those two versions around how we determine which properties are automatically ignored. Without seeing the precise schema change error you were seeing it's hard to know for sure.

@MacLean, it's incredibly unlikely it had anything to do with multithreading.

Comment: I have the same issues iOS 11. please anyone having the same issue..